# modify_header extension and headers not loading , browser is getting launched: Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-addon

You can check my code snippet below:
*I am getting one more error as I am using latest version of selenium*

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

se = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.add_extension(extension="C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\Resource Files\\modify_header_headers-0.1.7.xpi")
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 2)
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add")
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "x-msisdn")
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", '00012345731')
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", True)
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.action1", "Add")
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name1", "User-Agent")
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value1", 'Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/12.0.1987/37.7327; U; pl) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16')
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled1", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=se, firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("url")
driver.maximize_window()
# To check if header are enabled or not
driver.get("url/omt/ha")
```

Console warning:

```
C:\Users\*Name*\PycharmProjects\PythonTutorial\selenium_scripts\BrowserLoadWithHeader2.py:8: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
C:\Users\*Name*\PycharmProjects\PythonTutorial\selenium_scripts\BrowserLoadWithHeader2.py:20: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=se, firefox_profile=fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

It clear from the warning that you need to use options since firefox profile has been deprecated :

**Code :**

```
se = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 2)
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add")
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "x-msisdn")
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", '00012345731')
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", True)
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.action1", "Add")
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name1", "User-Agent")
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value1", 'Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/12.0.1987/37.7327; U; pl) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16')
options.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled1", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=se, options = options)
driver.get("url")
driver.maximize_window()
# To check if header are enabled or not
driver.get("url/omt/ha")
```